# Laravel 4: can one model serve several DB tables?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In my application I have several mysql tables: Toronto, Vancouver, Montreal, etc... and I am using the DB-class to work with them, eg.

```
$data = DB::select('select * from toronto where id = ?', array($id));
```

What I want to do is to start using Eloquent. I am new to Laravel and was just wondering if its possible to have one model work with several tables, smth like:

```
class City extends Eloquent {
      protected $table_a = 'toronto';
      protected $table_b = 'vancouver';
      protected $table_c = 'montreal';
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't how ORM's in general work. By the looks of your data structure you're not playing to SQL's strengths. Do each of your tables have the same column names by chance?

Comment: yes my tables are all the same. each has approx 100 rows (it could be 90 rows, or 110 rows though) and I update each city daily. Well, I could keep all the cities in one table but isn't it better to update them separately in terms of performance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It cannot, but you can. There are many ways, here's one:

Create your a City model that asks for a table name in its constructor:

```
class City extends Eloquent {

    public function __construct($city, array $attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->table = $city;
    }

}
```

To use it you'll have to instantiate your class using the table name:

```
$toronto = new City('toronto');
```

Then you can do anything you want with it:

```
var_dump( $toronto->where('id',701057)->get() );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `$model->setTable('mytable')` once you have a model instanciated, but for multiple tables I would rather recommend you make one "base" model with all the functionality you need and then several other classes which extend this class but define their own table with `protected $table = 'table'`.

However, in your case it sounds like you shouldn't be keeping the data in separate database tables at all. If you can find a way to store the state as a column instead of in separate tables, that would be better.