# Laravel Database Eloquent Relation queries for one model with multiple tables

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, relation

I've defined a Model for multiple tables as seen here:
[Laravel 4: can one model serve several DB tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576027/laravel-4-can-one-model-serve-several-db-tables)

I have many tables for the model Data:

- data_2000
- data_2001

  ...

And handle them in this model:

```
class Data extends \Eloquent {

    public function __construct($year, array $attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->table = 'data_' . $year;
    }

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Country');
    }
}
```

There's a One To Many relation with Country

```
class Country extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'countries';

    public function data($year)
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Data('.$year.')');
    }

    public function region()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Region');
    }
}
```

As I expected there's a missing argument if just return `$this->hasMany('Data')` so I tried `$this->hasMany('Data('.$year.')')` but of course it return an error of:

> Class 'Data(2000)' not found

Is there a workaround to get all the Country->data from all the tables or just one table using eloquent's methods? Or should I just run multiple queries for all the years with a `where('country_id', '=', $country->id)`?

Thanks in advance, any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26883036/3192276) may help you

Comment: @Razor That looks good, thank you, appreciated.